# Dealing with NumberFormatException

Tags: java, netbeans

```
private void Cubic_meter(){

        int v1 = Integer.parseInt(lbl_READING_NUMBER.getText());
        int a = Integer.parseInt(jLabel_PREVIOUS_READ.getText());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(jLabel_PRESENT_READ.getText());
        int cm = Math.abs(a-b);
    try{

        if(jLabel_PREVIOUS_READ.getText().equals("")){
    }

        if(jLabel_PRESENT_READ.getText().equals("")){
        }
    else{
        String sql = "UPDATE reading set Cubic_meter=? where Reading_Number=?";
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, cm);
        ps.setInt(2, v1);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    }catch(Exception e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Num berFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at mawasa_water_system.MainForm.Cubic_meter(MainForm. java:210)
at mawasa_water_system.MainForm.PREVIOUS_READING_OKAc tionPerformed(MainForm.java:3449)
at mawasa_water_system.MainForm.access$900(MainForm.j ava:18)
at mawasa_water_system.MainForm$13.actionPerformed(Ma inForm.java:830)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Abs tractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed (AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed (DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultB uttonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseRe leased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.jav a:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponen t.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:628 1)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:222 9)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.jav a:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.jav a:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:46 98)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent( Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(C ontainer.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Conta iner.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.jav a:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719 )
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:46 98)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.j ava:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103 )
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPri vilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPri vilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPri vilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java: 705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilter s(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(E ventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarch y(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispa tchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispa tchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThre ad.java:91)

If i use 
    NumberFormatException my

```
ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);,
ps.setInt(1, cm);,
ps.setInt(2,v1);,
ps.executeUpdate();
```

turns to error, why this so.

Answer (score 0):

You should define v1, a, and b AFTER you verify the getText is not empty.

```
    int v1 = Integer.parseInt(lbl_READING_NUMBER.getText());
    int a = Integer.parseInt(jLabel_PREVIOUS_READ.getText());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(jLabel_PRESENT_READ.getText());
    int cm = Math.abs(a-b);
```

Additionally,

```
if(jLabel_PREVIOUS_READ.getText().equals("")){

}
```

This does nothing regardless of whether there is text in previous read, seeing as there is no else if after it.